# Let $ T:\ell^2 (\Bbb Z_{N})\to\ell^2 (\Bbb Z_{N})$ be defined by $(T(z))(n)=z(n+1)-z(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

Let $T$ be a linear transformation of $\ell^2 (\Bbb Z_{N})$, for some given integer $N>0$.  I am being asked to find all the eigenvalues of $T$ but I don't quite know how to approach this.  Can I get some help?  I feel like there is too less information.

Comment: What is $Z_N$ ?

Comment: I gathered from the comments elsewhere that it represents the (finite set of) integers modulo $N$, so I made that clear. (Fairly strange to see the $\ell^2$ space of a finite set, but in the context of `fourier-analysis` I can understand the choice of notation). You complaint of "too less information" is not founded; this is a perfectly clear linear operator for which you can easily write down the matrix (on an obvious basis).

Answer (score 2):

If $Tz = \lambda z$, then

$$
\lambda z(n) = (Tz)(n) = z(n+1) - z(n)
$$

so $z(n+1) = (\lambda + 1)z(n)$ for all $n$.

Let $z$ be an eigenvector; if $z(1) = 0$, then $z(2) = 0$, implying $z(3) = 0$ and so forth. Thus $z(1) \neq 0$, and so we can assume it is $1$ (as eigenvectors are only determined up to scale). In this case, $z(n) = (1 + \lambda)^{n-1}$. Under what circumstances does a sequence defined this way belong to $\ell^2(Z_N)$?

Comment: How are you coming up with z(1)=0, z(2)=0 and so forth.  I don't understand what you're doing can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Either $z(1) = 0$ or it doesn't. If it does, then the fact that $z(n+1) = (\lambda + 1)z(n)$ means $z(2) = (\lambda + 1)0 = 0$, $z(3) = (\lambda + 1)0 = 0$, etc. That is, *all* entries of $z$ are zero. Since the sequence of all zeros *cannot* be an eigenvector, then we must have $z(1) \neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have cleared this up a long time ago, but what exactly does $Z_N$ denote here?

Comment: set of integers mod n

Comment: so this is square summable sequences of integers mod $n$?

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean.

Comment: This space consists of sequences $\{z(n)\}$ such that $\sum_n (z(n))^2 < \infty$ and with every $z(n)$ and integer mod $N$? In particular, it seems you can only have $\sum_n (z(n))^2 < \infty$ if $z(n) = 0$ eventually (if there is $N$ such that $z(n) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$).

Comment: On further thought, I guess only $(z(n))^2 = 0$ eventually is required.